# Issues building a calculator in JS

Tags: javascript

I'm a complete beginner at this and have started learning javascript through free code camp. I'm trying to write a program to make a calculator using basic javascript. My calculator seems to work fine except for it has a couple of issues that I want to fix. Edit to clarify what I'm asking for help here. Please run my codes in the snippet below with the following operation and you'll understand what I'm asking. Type 9-2 then hit '=' the calculator should display '7'. If you type a '2' immediately after the '7' is displayed, it will give you a '72' on the screen which is what I don't want it to do. I want it to reset to a blank screen. The other issue I have is a repeating display of operators. I've used the codes supplied by other commenters but they don't seem to work. I will keep searching for solution. Thank you all.

1. the operators: `+`, `-`, `*`, `/` and `.` are at this time can be repeated when pushing the button repeatedly. How do I create a function to only allow it to be displayed once.
2. After hitting the 'equal' button with the result displayed on the screen. If I pressed another number it would add on to the result instead of starting on a new screen. I need for it to reset and start a new using my current codes. 
   Any guidance and direction is appreciated. I have search Google for days now and still stuck. I'm also terrible at logic which I'm trying my best to wrap my head around this. Thanks.

```js
var show = document.getElementById('display');
var reset = false;

function clear() {
  if (reset) {
    show.value = '';
    reset = false;
  }
}

function toScreen(x) {
  clear();
  show.value += x;
  if (x === 'c') {
    show.value = '';
  }
}

function answer() {
  x = show.value;
  x = eval(x);
  show.value = x;
  reset = false;
}

function power() {
  x = show.value;
  x = eval(x * x);
  show.value = x;
}

function backspace() {
  var num = show.value;
  var len = num.length - 1;
  var newNum = num.substring(0, len);
  show.value = newNum;
}

function percent() {
  x = show.value;
  x = eval(x / 100);
  show.value = x;
}

function opposite() {
  var n = show.value;
  n = n * -1;
  show.value = n;
}

function sqrt() {
  var number = show.value;
  var ans = Math.sqrt(number);
  if (number < 0)
    ans = "Try a positive number!";
  show.value = ans;
}

function pie() {
  var pi = show.value;
  var result = Math.PI;
  show.value = result;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="display" disabled><br>

  <input type="button" value="C" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('c')">
  <input type="button" value="DEL" id="keys" onclick="backspace()">
  <input type="button" value="π" id="keys" onclick="pie()">
  <input type="button" value="+/-" id="keys" onclick="opposite()"><br>

  <input type="button" value="√" id="keys" onclick="sqrt()">
  <input type="button" value="%" id="keys" onclick="percent()">
  <input type="button" value="x^2" id="keys" onclick="power()">
  <input type="button" value="+" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('+')"><br>

  <input type="button" value="9" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('9')">
  <input type="button" value="8" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('8')">
  <input type="button" value="7" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('7')">
  <input type="button" value="-" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('-')"><br>

  <input type="button" value="6" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('6')">
  <input type="button" value="5" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('5')">
  <input type="button" value="4" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('4')">
  <input type="button" value="*" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('*')"><br>

  <input type="button" value="3" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('3')">
  <input type="button" value="2" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('2')">
  <input type="button" value="1" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('1')">
  <input type="button" value="/" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('/')"><br>

  <input type="button" value="0" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('0')">
  <input type="button" value="." id="keys" onclick="toScreen('.')">
  <input type="button" value="=" id="equal" onclick="answer()"><br>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

See the codes

Here is the perfectly working code. You can replace x with i some places like:

```
function power() {
  x = eval(i * i);
  show.value = x;
  reset = true;
}
```

Problem fixed:

1. Your 1st & 2nd problem
2. Your code didn't check is input starting from a num. or operator (/1, *1)
3. Your code didn't check for invalid input (1+, 1+1+ etc)
4. Your code also not clear screen (like in case of anser) after power Pi etc
5. Your function like PI Power not check if input is a number (power of 8*) see the power function:

```js
var show = document.getElementById('display');
var reset = false;
var i = "";  //store what is typed

function clear() {
  if (reset) {
    i = '';
    show.value = i;
    reset = false;
  }
}

function toScreen(x) {
  clear();
  if (x === "+" || x === "-" || x === "*" || x === "/" || x === ".") {
    if (i.charAt(i.length - 1)  === x) {
      return false;
    }
    if (i.length === 0) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  i += x;
  if (x === 'c') {
    i = '';
  }
  show.value = i;
}

function answer() {
  var op = ["+", "-", "*", ".", "/"];
  for (a=0; a<op.length; a++) {
    if (i.charAt(i.length - 1) === op[a]) {
      alert("Wrong input");
      return false;
    }
  }
  x = show.value;
  x = eval(x);
  show.value = x;
  reset = true;
}

function power() {
  if (isNaN(i)) {
     alert("please enter a valid number");
     return false;
   }
  x = show.value;
  x = eval(x * x);
  show.value = x;
  reset = true;
}

function backspace() {
  var num = show.value;
  var len = num.length - 1;
  var newNum = num.substring(0, len);
  show.value = newNum;
  reset = true;
}

function percent() {
  x = show.value;
  x = eval(x / 100);
  show.value = x;
  reset = true;
}

function opposite() {
  var n = show.value;
  n = n * -1;
  show.value = n;
  reset = true;
}

function sqrt() {
  var number = show.value;
  var ans = Math.sqrt(number);
  if (number < 0)
    ans = "Try a positive number!";
  show.value = ans;
  reset = true;
}

function pie() {
  var pi = show.value;
  var result = Math.PI;
  show.value = result;
  reset = true;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="display" disabled><br>

  <input type="button" value="C" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('c')">
  <input type="button" value="DEL" id="keys" onclick="backspace()">
  <input type="button" value="π" id="keys" onclick="pie()">
  <input type="button" value="+/-" id="keys" onclick="opposite()"><br>

  <input type="button" value="√" id="keys" onclick="sqrt()">
  <input type="button" value="%" id="keys" onclick="percent()">
  <input type="button" value="x^2" id="keys" onclick="power()">
  <input type="button" value="+" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('+')"><br>

  <input type="button" value="9" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('9')">
  <input type="button" value="8" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('8')">
  <input type="button" value="7" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('7')">
  <input type="button" value="-" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('-')"><br>

  <input type="button" value="6" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('6')">
  <input type="button" value="5" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('5')">
  <input type="button" value="4" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('4')">
  <input type="button" value="*" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('*')"><br>

  <input type="button" value="3" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('3')">
  <input type="button" value="2" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('2')">
  <input type="button" value="1" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('1')">
  <input type="button" value="/" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('/')"><br>

  <input type="button" value="0" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('0')">
  <input type="button" value="." id="keys" onclick="toScreen('.')">
  <input type="button" value="=" id="equal" onclick="answer()"><br>
</form>
```

Comment: I ran your code on the 'code snippet' above and that didn't work. I typed in 7-4 then hit '=' it gave me an answer but if I hit another number like '4' button it would add that number to '7-4' and showed '7-44' instead of clearing out the display and only shows '4'.

Comment: @silkshocker See the edited answer. Hope everything is working perfect now. Accept and upvote if you like it.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Now I'm running into an issue where I cannot perform an operation on top of the result displayed. For example, after hitting '=' button to get me a value of say '7' if I want to press '+' to add another number to this without clearing the screen, the '+' sign doesn't appear and I can't do the arithmetic. It's strange because my previous code before the edition allows me to do that.

Comment: @silkshocker Your problem no. 2 avoid this. If you want to clear screen only for numbers try it your self.This is not a free coding site.

Answer (score 0):

```
function answer() {
  x = show.value;
  x = eval(x);
  show.value = x;
  reset = true;
}
```

Change the reset to true, so that it clears the show.value to be an empty string, that solves nr.2 for you

Comment: Yes, it solves my issue for #2 but creates another problem which is if I pressed an operator like '/' it would only display the operator without a number before it. For example, when I pressed '9-2' then '=' the screen displayed '7' at this point if I pressed '/' it would display '/' without the '7' before it which is what I don't want. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Edit your `toScreen()` function to only add your `operator` if it was
>      not previously typed:

```
function toScreen(x) {
  clear();
  var notTwice = ['+', '-', '*', '/', '.']; //List of chars that should not be repeated
  if(notTwice.indexOf(x) > -1){
    if(show.value.slice(-1) != x){ //Only type it if it wasn't typed right before
      show.value += x;
    }
  }
  else{
    show.value += x;
  }
  if (x === 'c') {
    show.value = '';
  }
}
```

> 2. Just set `reset` to `false` in your `answer()` function.

Here is a working snippet for you :

```js
var show = document.getElementById('display');
var reset = false;
var i = "";  //store what is typed

function clear() {
  if (reset) {
    i = '';
    show.value = i;
    reset = false;
  }
}

function toScreen(x) {
  clear();
  var notTwice = ['+', '-', '*', '/', '.']; //List of chars that should not be repeated
  if(notTwice.indexOf(x) > -1){
    if(show.value.slice(-1) != x){ //Only type it if it wasn't typed right before
      show.value += x;
    }
  }
  else{
    show.value += x;
  }
  if (x === 'c') {
    show.value = '';
  }
}

function answer() {
  var op = ["+", "-", "*", ".", "/"];
  for (a=0; a<op.length; a++) {
    if (i.charAt(i.length - 1) === op[a]) {
      alert("Wrong input");
      return false;
    }
  }
  x = show.value;
  x = eval(x);
  show.value = x;
  reset = false;
}

function power() {
  if (isNaN(i)) {
     alert("please enter a valid number");
     return false;
   }
  x = show.value;
  x = eval(x * x);
  show.value = x;
  reset = true;
}

function backspace() {
  var num = show.value;
  var len = num.length - 1;
  var newNum = num.substring(0, len);
  show.value = newNum;
  reset = true;
}

function percent() {
  x = show.value;
  x = eval(x / 100);
  show.value = x;
  reset = true;
}

function opposite() {
  var n = show.value;
  n = n * -1;
  show.value = n;
  reset = true;
}

function sqrt() {
  var number = show.value;
  var ans = Math.sqrt(number);
  if (number < 0)
    ans = "Try a positive number!";
  show.value = ans;
  reset = true;
}

function pie() {
  var pi = show.value;
  var result = Math.PI;
  show.value = result;
  reset = true;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="display" disabled><br>

  <input type="button" value="C" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('c')">
  <input type="button" value="DEL" id="keys" onclick="backspace()">
  <input type="button" value="π" id="keys" onclick="pie()">
  <input type="button" value="+/-" id="keys" onclick="opposite()"><br>

  <input type="button" value="√" id="keys" onclick="sqrt()">
  <input type="button" value="%" id="keys" onclick="percent()">
  <input type="button" value="x^2" id="keys" onclick="power()">
  <input type="button" value="+" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('+')"><br>

  <input type="button" value="9" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('9')">
  <input type="button" value="8" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('8')">
  <input type="button" value="7" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('7')">
  <input type="button" value="-" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('-')"><br>

  <input type="button" value="6" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('6')">
  <input type="button" value="5" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('5')">
  <input type="button" value="4" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('4')">
  <input type="button" value="*" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('*')"><br>

  <input type="button" value="3" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('3')">
  <input type="button" value="2" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('2')">
  <input type="button" value="1" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('1')">
  <input type="button" value="/" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('/')"><br>

  <input type="button" value="0" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('0')">
  <input type="button" value="." id="keys" onclick="toScreen('.')">
  <input type="button" value="=" id="equal" onclick="answer()"><br>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the codes but they don't display other numbers. Only the operators. I couldn't get the number to display on the screen using your codes.

Comment: I forgot an `else`. It's fixed now.

Comment: Thanks but it still doesn't fix the issue where after I press '=' to get the result and want to press '+' to add another number to the result. The display would show '+' without a number instead of let say 3+3. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Just set `reset` to `false` in your `answer()` function. I updated my answer with a working snippet.

Comment: I just did and that didn't work. I copied and pasted the whole code blocks from above and even changed reset to 'false' in my answer() function.

Comment: Does it work within the snippet I gave you? If so some other code on your side must interfere with it.